# How does Aavegotchi attach wearable NFTs to gotchi NFTs?

Tags: nft, aave

Aavegotchi (and presumably many other NFT games) have different types of NFTs, some of which can be attached to others.

For example:

- An Aavegotchi ghost, or gotchi, is an NFT with attributes that help define one gotchi from another. You can buy and sell gotchis on the market. They seem like pretty standard NFTs.
- There are also separate "wearable" NFTs. They, too, can be bought and sold on the market, have fairly unique attributes, and exist on their own -- separate from any gotchi NFT.
- You can attach wearable NFTs to a gotchi NFT. Once attached to your gotchi, the wearables change the base attributes of the gotchi.
- Where the gotchi goes, the wearables go -- if you were to sell your gotchi in the "baazaar" or market, then any attached wearables go with it. Whoever owns the gotchi, can detach any wearables and now buy and sell them separately again.

How does this attaching of one NFT to another NFT work? Is it just another property of the one NFT that references another NFT -- so not much different than any other property? When a gotchi with wearables is sold, do all the NFTs involved have to be updated to change ownership?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just another property of the one NFT that references another NFT ?

Yes it probably is, i don't see any complex solution for this.

> When a gotchi with wearables is sold, do all the NFTs involved have to be updated to change ownership?

if the wearables are independent NFTs then yes they will have to change too. by this definition the price of a **gotchis** will increase linearly with the amount of attached **Wearables**